# ViewBinding giving null pointer exception

Tags: android-viewbinding

I am getting null pointer exception while using viewBinding. I have checked that i have properly done all the steps to use viewbinding.

Now binding.progressbar is not giving null but binding.viewPager is giving null.

Comment: you must provide id to view pager and then you can access that using that id

Comment: as i have mentioned. I have done all the steps correctly which includes the giving an id too. so the thing is that I changed the viewpager to viewPage2 in layout file and now someHow viewBinding is saying that  it might be null while all the other views are accessable.So i introduced fresh textView and gave it an id and then using binding.txtView.setVisibility() is giving the warning that it might be null.

Comment: i have cleaned the code, restart and ivalidate the cahce etc. but nothing helped